# How to load Json data onto a Charts.js chart

Tags: javascript, ajax, console, chart.js

I would like to display the data variable "temp" which is listed by ID under (.list) on the following Json (http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=53.4808&lon=2.2426&appid=4ce23fd03d1558816c3ef6efb6a5ec30&units=metric) as an x axis variable on this chart:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    // The type of chart we want to create
    type: 'line',

    // The data for our dataset
    data: {
        labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'My First dataset',
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45]
        }]
    },

    // Configuration options go here
    options: {}
});



<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

The chart currently functions alone without the Json data. How would I import this specified data so that it can replace the "data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45]" variables?

Comment: start by learning how to use the fetch API, and JSON.parse.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp

Comment: Maybe it's me, but I'm missing how this question and code relates to Java programming. Are you sure that you added this language tag correctly to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your main stumbling block is retrieving the data from the API, all you need are three steps:

1. Making a network request to the URL you posted, usually done using fetch. This asks the openweathermap website to send you some data.

```
const response = await fetch('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=53.4808&lon=2.2426&appid=4ce23fd03d1558816c3ef6efb6a5ec30&units=metric');
```

This will give you an object of type Response, which is not what you want since it includes HTTP headers etc. which you have no use for. You want the JSON data sent as part of the response.

2. Extracting the JSON

```
const data = await response.json()
```

3. Parsing the JSON variable for the temp values

```
const chartData = data.list.map((object) => object.main.temp)
```

Explanation: The JSON object returned by the API contains a "list" array that itself contains a "main" attribute, that finally contains the temp you're looking for. "json.list" access the list, the map is taking each object and creating a new array (I believe) containing the "temp" value inside the "main" object.

Lmk if that wasn't clear!

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, I added this code however could not figure out how to draw this data to the graph: https://jsfiddle.net/ygkut2Lq/

Comment: A few notes: you had an underscore between await and fetch in two places, fetch won't work in most websites (including JS fiddle if you're trying to fetch a website using HTTP since jsfiddle is loaded over HTTPS) and you need to assign the data attribute inside your chart to chartData. If that doesn't work try updating the data after the object creation